# PHP Documentor --output option

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have installed PHP Documentor through PEAR. but output option is not working.
when i use simple command like

> phpdoc -d source/path -t target/path --template responsive

it works fine. but when i use -o or --output option like this

> phpdoc -d source/path -t target/path -o PDF:default:*

it gives following error.

> [RuntimeException]
>
> The "-o" option does not exist.

i have tried other output formats as well like -o HTML:Smarty:PHP and -o HTML:Smarty:default but the result is same.

Answer (score 3):

the -o option does not exist on phpdocs 2
Look option whit:

```
phpdoc -h
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. and yes its not there. but then again how can i get pdf output in phpdocs 2?

Comment: I think export to pdf is removing on this version.  You'd have to install the old version.

Comment: new versions usually came up with new features not with removal of old ones. so i believe there got to be a way to get different kind of outputs in php documentor 2 as well.

Comment: Keep in mind phpdocs2 is still in alpha stage, it even has its own alpha-channel in pear. If you want to know what the final release will contain, either wait for it or follow the github project here: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues?milestone=15&state=open

Answer (score 1):

In the new version 2. * yet there is no such pdf template. There is not also the option -o.

there are only http://www.phpdoc.org/templates

template selection

```
phpdoc --template="clean" --template="checkstyle" -d .
```

---

BTW I use the older version (1.4.4) I wanted to save to pdf.

```
phpdoc -o PDF:default:default -t ./docs -d ./
```

But created an bad document. Maybe version 1.4.4 does not work with PHP 5.5.11 on the issue in PDF format.

I managed in version 1.4.4  only generate HTML.

```
phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli -t ./docs -d ./
```

So I went back to version 2 * and I wait pdf template.